# Where do I store my django project code when using apache and mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm looking at what appears to be conflicting information on django's website.

On this page:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

It says:

> It’s not a good idea to put any of this Python code within your Web
>   server’s document root, because it risks the possibility that people
>   may be able to view your code over the Web. That’s not good for
>   security.
>
> Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as
>   /home/mycode.

However, on this page:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
It says this is how Apache should be set up:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Doesn't the latter show the project files in the www root?

So which is correct? The former or the latter?

I have used these linux commands to set up the project:

```
cd /home/personal/network/django
django-admin.py startproject djnet
```

I then put this into httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/personal/network/django/djnet/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/personal/network/django
<Directory /home/personal/network/django/djnet>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

This works, but I'm worried about the "That’s not good for security" line in the first page I've referenced.

Am I supposed to put the project code generated by `django-admin startproject` in a directory separate from the Apache directory? If so, how would I configure Apache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, why do you say it shows the files in the document root? It doesn't, it shows them in "/path/to/mysite.com". What you have done is correct, and isn't in the web root either.

Comment: OK thank you. I see it now. I was getting myself confused with other Apache settings in my httpd.conf